# How to backup files in /Document directory to iCloud?

Tags: core-data, backup, icloud

I use CoreData to managed data. My app creates pictures, movies, and audios. I save the media files directly to the /Document directory. I use url in coreData to access the media files. I can sync the sqlite file with iCloud, but how can I sync the media files to iCloud?